# Selenium behaves differently between ipython and a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape the New York State [directory of trial judges](https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/judicialdirectory/JudicialDirectory). The site checks whether javascript is enabled and renders the page with a short warning about needing python. So I've been trying Selenium.

However, when I run the following line by line in ipython or python, it is able to access the page fine. Then, if I run this from the command line (`python scraper.py`), the site renders with the javascript warning - but only the first time I hit the site. This happens:

- regardless of what browser I use,
- whether I run it as a headless browser or not,
- regardless of what cookies I try to set

My code:

```
import string
import csv
from selenium import webdriver

# Start the browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(
    "https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/judicialdirectory/JudicialDirectory")
print(browser.title)

# You can run the above 4 lines directly in ipython,
# but if running from the command line, the previous try will not work
browser.get(
    "https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/judicialdirectory/JudicialDirectory")
print(browser.title)
```

In case it's of import: I'm running this on Windows 10.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to debug this?

Comment: I'll bet that you're just catching the title before the JS has a chance to execute. Try putting a wait after `browser.get(...)` and see if that helps.

Comment: That was exactly what it was - thank you! I'll add what I've done as an answer, but am happy to accept yours if you want to write an answer.

Comment: Do you mean that `print(browser.title)` doesn't work?

Comment: @Andersson The title would change depending on if the page was showing the javascript warning or not, so was the easiest way to tell if something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference here is that, when run as a script, `browser.title` is being accessed before the JS actually has a chance to execute. You can avoid this by putting a wait after getting the page. Using `time.sleep` is simple

```
browser.get(...)
time.sleep(1.5)
```

However, this may result in you waiting longer than needed. So it would be better to use selenium's [expected condition support](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits). This way you'll only wait as long as you need to.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

condition = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "some_element_id_present_after_JS_load"))
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(condition)
print(driver.title)
# ...
```

Comment: You should be able to create a custom wait that waits until the title changes. That would be a better approach than a hardcoded sleep.

Comment: @JeffC my answer does include using an expected condition as an alternative to `time.sleep`. You could make an EC that waits for a title *change*, but I think waiting for some element (or some specific title) I think might be safer. Consider a case where the JS *does* get executed before you start waiting, you'll end up hitting a timeout. OTOH, if you wait on an element, it doesn't matter if the element is present before you start waiting.

Comment: If you wait for a title change and the title is wrong, you wont get a timeout but you will fail the assert. If you wait for a specific title change and the title is wrong, you will get a timeout exception instead of an assert fail. I would prefer to get the assert fail rather than a timeout exception but maybe that's just me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by failing the assert, maybe I've misunderstood your meaning. If you do `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(condition)`, if the condition is never met, a `TimeoutException` will be thrown. The supposition is that the title is liable to change *before* you even start waiting, therefore the condition will not be met, and a `TimeoutException` will be thrown stopping the script after waiting for 10 seconds. If you wait on something you know will be present, rather than for a change to occur, you eliminate the risk of this race condition.

Comment: I'm assuming at some point that an Assert will be used to compare the expected title to the actual title. If those don't match, the Assert will fail. That's what I'm referring to when I say fail the assert.

Comment: I guess my thought was to capture the current title, perform some action that navigates to another page, then wait for the title to not be the original title. You should avoid the race condition along with not throwing a timeout if the title doesn't match which also saves time. If the title changes in 1 sec, you will fail the assert then. If you wait 10s for the title to equal something, then you wasted 9s.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand better what you mean. I can almost put the pieces together in my head. I think that would work nicely, as long as you can be confident of the pre-JS title... or that the post-JS title is not the same as the current or pre-JS title. It seems that in your scenario there are 3 titles you may need to consider: the current title before navigation, the title after navigation before JS execution, and the title after JS execution. An interesting thought to say the least. Maybe consider providing an answer of your own with this.

Answer (score 0):

I used Selenium's [WebDriverWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) function, which fixed the problem.

```
browser.get(
    "https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/judicialdirectory/JudicialDirectory")
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
             EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "column1_A630"))) # a random element
print([i.text for i in element.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'JUDGE_ID')]")])
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

While you invoke the *url* `https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/judicialdirectory/JudicialDirectory` the *WebClient* i.e. *FirefoxBrowser* achieves **`document.readyState`** equal to **`complete`** at a certain stage but that doesn't garuntees that all the associated *Javascript* and *Ajax Calls* have completed.

Now if you look at the `<head>` tag within the *HTML* containing the *Page Title* which gets rendered after a certain *Javascript* completes as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="ucs-jd-internet-page-BioPage-0">
/*<![CDATA[*/

    function clearDefaultandCSS(el) {
      if (el.defaultValue == el.value)
    el.value = "";
    }

/*]]>*/
</script>
<title>Judicial Directory</title>
```

So untill the related *Javascript* completes rendering the *Page Title* is not rendered. Hence you are unable to retrieve the actual *Page Title*.

In these cases the best approach would be to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in-conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause set as [**title_contains**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_contains) as follows :

```
browser.get("https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/judicialdirectory/JudicialDirectory")
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.title_contains(("Judicial Directory")))
print(browser.title)
browser.quit()
```